Проксирование web трафика vCloud Director
необходимо выполнить перенаправление трафика на web часть vCloud Director.
У меня есть сервер на Debian который занимается перенаправлением трафика, он получает из интернета по портам данные (http, https) далее из названия домена он уже решает куда перенаправлять трафик в локальной сети. Также сделано и из локальной сети.
То есть локальный домен отправляет на один адрес (ретранслятор), а он уже поставляет сертификат Let’s Encrypt, и отправляет на сайт по ip.
Вот пример того как я делаю это обычно.
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name "site-domain-name";

        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_pass https://IP:443;
        }
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/site-domain-name/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/site-domain-name/privkey.pem;
 # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = site-domain-name) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

        listen 80;
        server_name site-domain-name;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}

По привычной схеме я создал отдельный файл еще и под vCloud Director в ретрансляторе и написал схожий конфиг заменив имена и IP.
Аутентификация работает на сайте, но далее загружается часть интерфейса и все стопорится.
Вид в консоли:

Далее немного информации, которая может пригодиться, которую я собрал пытаясь выяснить, что я упускаю:
У vCloud Director
2 сетевых интерфейса и 2 основных порта (443, 8443), из которых как я понял работает только 443.
2 интерфейса находятся в одной подсети. Сразу скажу, что доступность абсолютно вся есть.
Также хочу сказать, что если прокидывать через NAT порт 443 напрямую на 1-й IP vCloud Director, то этого становится достаточно для работы и он работает замечательно (помогите).
Подытожим:
Мне нужно перенаправлять трафик на vCloud Director любым способом, можно даже не NGINX.(по доменному имени)
Я понимаю, что покупка отдельного IP решит проблему на изи.(мы бедный колледж)
У нас уже 13 веб-сервисов которые торчат то-тут то-там. На 1 внешнем ip.
Всем заранее спасибо если откликнитесь, буду очень благодарен.
